# Spark: Why is my UDF not called in rdd map?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code

```
def get_general_popularity_count():
    def test(t):
        a = 1 # this is just a random variable for testing
        print "a"
        pickle.dump(a, open("a.p", "wb"))
    count_dict = pickle.load(open("list.p","rb"))
    rdd = session.sparkContext.parallelize(count_dict)
    rdd.map(lambda x:test(x))
```

However, nothing is printed, and pickle didn't save a file either. In fact, I know that the UDF was never called because once I had a syntax error in `test(x)`, but the program never caught it.
So why is my UDF never called? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It is not called because `map` is a transformation. Unless it is followed by an action Spark has no reason to execute it at all.

Furthermore your code is not a good choice for Apache Spark:

- `print` outputs data to the standard output of the worker.
- `pickle.dump` will write to a local file system of the worker and, when execute like this in `map`, overwrite output all over again.

You could try `RDD.foreach` or `RDD.saveAsPickleFile`

Comment: Thank you very much. From what I see from the documentation, `foreach` performs on each cluster, so if I have a local dictionary and I want to run some sort of function on each row in the rdd, and add that to the dictionary, how would that work?